# Level $k$ bounds in Analysis of Boolean functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, boolean-functions, fourier-analysis

In Ryan O'Donnell's book *Analysis of Boolean functions*, following Corollary 9.25 the following appears:

If $f\colon \{-1,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$, and we have $\mathbb{E}[f] = \alpha$, then for any integer $k$ at most $2\ln \frac{1}{\alpha}$, we have $W^{\leq k}[f] \leq \rho^{-k}\alpha^{2(1-\rho)}$. He then deduces the following corollary:

> If $\epsilon > 0$ and $k_\epsilon = 2(1-\epsilon)\ln \frac{1}{\alpha}$, then 
>   $W^{\leq k_\epsilon}[f] \leq \alpha^{\epsilon^2}$

My question is isn't this bound meaningless?

Indeed, we have

$W^{\leq k_\epsilon}[f] \leq \lVert f\rVert_2^2 = \alpha \ll \alpha^{\epsilon^2}$

Comment: For $0 < \epsilon < 1$, we have $a^{\epsilon^2} \ll a$, not the other way around.

Comment: @RobertAndrews But $a<1$...

Comment: My mistake, I completely missed that.

Comment: I may be very confused, but that seems right — the bound looks vacuous, unless I am missing something as well. If you're right, however, the actual bound obtained (see Exercise 9.19) is $$2(\varepsilon+(1-\varepsilon)\ln(1-\varepsilon))$$which is non-vacuous (greater than $1$) when $\varepsilon\geq 0.81$.

Comment: @ClementC. I agree, but it kinda of suck we don't have a workable estimate for the full range of $\epsilon$, i.e you get interesting stuff both for $\epsilon$ close to $1$, and for constant $k$. I guess if I'm not missing something someone should answer so we can close the question

Comment: @Andy Well, there is some magic number $c$ (roughly, $c\approx 1.582$) such that, setting $$k_\varepsilon = \frac{1}{c\ln(2e)}\cdot (1-\varepsilon)\ln\frac{1}{\alpha}$$ you get $$W^{\leq k_\varepsilon}[f] \leq \alpha^{1+\varepsilon-O(\varepsilon^2)}$$

Comment: The level $k$ inequality has been improved by Chin Ho Lee, Fourier Bounds and Pseudorandom Generators for
Product Tests. See Lemma 10 [here](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2019/10829/pdf/LIPIcs-CCC-2019-7.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just posting an answer in order to close the question.

See the helpful comments to the question which contain all the info;

1. Yes it is vacuous, but if you use the stronger bound you get something nontrivial for large $\epsilon$, of course for fixed $k$ you also have interesting things, it's just the estimates in the book lose too much.
2. Better bounds are known (thanks ot Yuval) : http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2019/10829/pdf/LIPIcs-CCC-2019-7.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with 2. As shown in my comment, the issue is not so much the tightness of the bounds used (although, of course, it cannot hurt to use the improved bound of Chin Ho Lee) as much as a bad choice of $k_\varepsilon$. Replace the leading constant $2$ in the current setting by some constant less than 1, you will get something non-vacuous.

Comment: @ClementC. Yeah sure I wasn't phrasing myself well

Answer (score 1):

This statement has been removed from the [latest version of the textbook](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.10386.pdf) and the referenced problem (9.19) has been updated to prove a weaker result instead.